# ArrayAdapter Initializing not Clear

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I am trying to create a list containing names of all the available Applications on a Phone by triggering an Implicit intent. Being a beginner in android I am following tutorials from a book. I have created custom Adapters by extending ArrayAdapter before but the syntax of this simple ArrayAdapter is not being clear to me. Here it is:

```
ArrayAdapter<ResolveInfo> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<ResolveInfo> (getActivity(),android.R.layout.activity_list_item,activities)
{
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View v =  super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        TextView tv = (TextView)v;
        ResolveInfo ri = getItem (position);
        tv.setText(ri.loadLabel(pm));
        return v;
    }
};
```

1- Why is the method getView being called in within parenthesis after calling constructor of ArrayAdapter?

2- Is this some kind of Anonymous class structure?

3- Is this in reality a custom adapter for Object type of ResolveInfo?

Any Help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: 1/ see #2. 2/ yes. 3/ yes.

Comment: Thanks, Can you please explain how this is an anonymous class structure by an example? That will be a favour.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)` is called within the brackets because you are constructing a `new` array adapter, and therefore must provide the required methods for the adapter.
2. Yes that is exactly what it is
3. Yes, you are creating a customized `ArrayAdapter` for Arrays of the object ResolveInfo,

I assume you have previously extended the ArrayAdapter Class by implementing your own Java Class file, this essentially is doing the same thing. The benefit to implementing your own Java Class file is thatyou can use the same `ArrayAdapter` anywhere in your project. However, if this is the only place you will need this adapter, it may be better to implement it this way.

Comment: Thank You very much. This made things a bit clear.

Btw is ArrayAdapter only for Arrays by default and if it needs to handle any other object we need a custom adapter?

Comment: @UmairRiaz yes you'll need a custom Adapter for custom objects.